# C++ why does new keyword works and malloc does not?

Tags: c++, pointers, malloc, new-operator

I'm learning about pointers and structures and I ran into this hard to understand the problem for me.
I have created this simple program for testing purpose:

```
#include <iostream>

struct testStructure
{
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
    int c = 400;
};

int main()
{
    struct testStructure* testStruct;
    testStruct = new testSctructure;

    std::cout << testStruct->c;

    delete testStruct;
    return 0;
}
```

the above program works just fine, it prints the value 400. But when i try to do it with malloc:

```
#include <iostream>

struct testStructure
{
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
    int c = 400;
};

int main()
{
    struct testStructure* testStruct;
    testStruct = (testStructure*)malloc(sizeof testStructure);

    std::cout << testStruct->c;

    free(testStruct);
    return 0;
}
```

it gives me this value:
-842150451

Why?
The above examples were written and build in Visual Studio 2019.

I know that in C++ you should almost always want to use new keyword but I wanted to experiment a bit.

Comment: In the second case, you have allocated memory, but it has not been initialized yet.  Undefined behavior.

Comment: `-842150451` is a magic debugging code. `0xcdcdcdcd` see here what that means: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127386/in-visual-studio-c-what-are-the-memory-allocation-representations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127386/in-visual-studio-c-what-are-the-memory-allocation-representations)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`new` initializes the allocated memory with the class' constructor (which is implicit in this this case).

`malloc` performs no initialization, it just allocates a portion of memory. Reading uninitiazlied memory will have undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how your second example can be made to work.  In general, this is not a recommended way of working with C++, but there are some valid use cases.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

struct testStructure {
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
    int c = 400;
};

int main() {
    auto testStruct_memory = std::malloc(sizeof(testStructure));

    // In-place constructor.
    auto testStruct = new(testStruct_memory) testStructure();

    std::cout << testStruct->c << "\n";

    // In-place destructor.
    testStruct->~testStructure();

    std::free(testStruct_memory);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In the case of malloc, you allocated a block of memory, but did not create an object. The `testStructure` constructor was not called.

You could call the constructor on the memory area with a placement new:

```
char* ptr = malloc(sizeof testStructure);
testStruct = new(ptr) testStructure;
```

but this is hard to read, confusing, hard to maintain, and fraught with risk. For example, you need

- to free() not delete ptr
- you need to similarly explicitly call the destructor.

So, not recommended.